# Maven JBoss7 deployment: ConnectException

Tags: maven, jboss7.x, remote-server

JBoss 7.1.5 is up and running.
I can access the management upon `http://127.0.0.1:9990/console`

I created the following Maven profile to deploy:

```
<profile>
    <id>localDeploy</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.9.Final</version>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
                    <port>9990</port>
                    <username>username</username>
                    <password>pw</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

No matter what I try, when running `mvn jboss-as:deploy -P localDeploy`, it always fails with

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.9.Final:deploy (default- cli) on project [project-name]: Could not execute goal deploy on [name].ear.
Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection timed out
```

Comment: JBoss's documentation at https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html lists a different port value as default - 9999. Could you please check with that configuration?

Comment: @Illya Kysil Port 9999 is configured for the native management interface, so I thought I should use 9990. I also think I tried port 9999 with the same result, but maybe you are right and JBoss is not listening to 9999 because of a configuration issue. I'll have to check on Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`netstat -ano | grep "9999"` showed that the server is not listening.

The `management-interfaces` section in the standalone.xml was missing

```
<native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
    <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
</native-interface>
```

Props to @Illya Kysil for pointing me into the right direction.